# Echo Query Without "q=/index.php"?

Tags: php

Right now I'm using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to echo the query on the page and for it ended up looking like this:

```
q=/index.php&utm_domain=
```

I'm not sure why the `q=/index.php` part is appearing, but I just want it to display `utm_domain=`

I also tried

```
http_build_query($_GET)
```

but I have no idea why this is happening since I haven't seen it before.. how do i fix this so it displays only the query?

Comment: If I had to guess, you have some URL rewriting in place that modifies the request

Comment: @Phil its a wordpress site so how woul di fix this?

Comment: If you *"just want it to display `utm_domain=`*" then be specific, eg `echo 'utm_domain=', $_GET['utm_domain'];`

Comment: @Phil theres more to the query string, but i just want to echo the whole thing without the `q=index.php` part

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've got some URL rewriting or similar that sets the `q` parameter to the original request.

You can easily filter out the `q` parameter when displaying the query string. For example

```
$query = http_build_query(array_filter($_GET, function($key) {
    return $key !== 'q';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

Comment: @JoeBobby was just missing a `)`. Fixed now